# Does IBM Visual Recognition Support other Data labelling method aside from Bounding Boxes

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, bounding-box, watson-studio, visual-recognition

I'm trying to build a **weed detection model**  using IBM Visual Recognition service. I have successfully annotated my images with bounding box but the when i try to evaluate my model on a new test image, the model misclassified the new image. I want to know if **IBM WATSON** support other labelling technique aside from Bounding Box. technique like **polygon annotation, semantic, line e-t-c**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it only supports bounding boxes for object detection.

Comment: Can I build my own custom detection model using the IBM deep learning Architecture..??

Comment: You can train an object detection model with your own types of objects, but you cannot change things about the model like what type of neural net it uses or training hyperparameters.  See https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/visual-recognition/visual-recognition-v4 and https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/visual-recognition?topic=visual-recognition-object-detection-overview